# What are GetField, SetField, GetProperty and SetProperty in BindingFlags enumeration?

Tags: .net, reflection, propertyinfo, fieldinfo

I have no idea what these are for. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) is not very clear:

> **GetField** Specifies that the value of the specified field should be returned.
>
> **SetField** Specifies that the value of the specified field should be set.
>
> **GetProperty** Specifies that the value of the specified property should be returned.
>
> **SetProperty** Specifies that the value of the specified property should be set. For COM properties, specifying this binding flag is equivalent to specifying PutDispProperty and PutRefDispProperty.

If I specify them in `BindingFlags` enumeration, what should they return? I thought it has to do with properties and fields of a type, but this simple test says no:

```
class Base
{
    int i;
    int I { get; set; }

    void Do()
    {

    }
}

print typeof(Base).GetMembers(BindingFlags.GetField 
                              | BindingFlags.Instance 
                              | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// Int32 get_I()
// Void set_I(Int32)
// Void Do()
// Void Finalize()
// System.Object MemberwiseClone()
// Int32 I
// Int32 i
// Int32 <I>k__BackingField
```

The same set is returned for `SetField`, `GetProperty` and `SetProperty`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of these are not needed to enumerate but rather to access properties properly. For example, to set a value of the property on given instance, you need SetProperty flag.

```
 Base b;

 typeof(Base).InvokeMember( "I", 
     BindingFlags.SetProperty|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance,
     ...,
     b, new object[] { newvalue } );
```

but to get the value of this property, you would need to use the GetProperty:
flag.

```
 Base b;

 int val = (int)typeof(Base).InvokeMember( "I", 
     BindingFlags.GetProperty|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance,
     ...,
     b, null);
```

Comment: Agree, could be kind of confusing.